# ListView horizontal like Gallery or any another in place of gallery?

Tags: android, listview, gallery

I want to implement the horizontal list view as same like gallery. I am getting the images for assets folder and show in gallery like. Gallery just debricated in the android jelly bean so I does not want to use this. Is there any solution that I can use the in place of gallery.

Comment: use HorizonalScrollView and put ImageView as child of HorizontalScrollView

Comment: @Brijesh Thakur is right you have to use HorizontalScrollView

Comment: provide me any example for the same

Comment: yea use Horizontalscrollview for it. 
If you need a ready made architectue use   https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"                 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:scrollbars="none"
     android:isScrollContainer="true">

<ImageView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```